# Is HTML a good start for programming?

Tags: html

I would like to start learning programming and making web pages and have started with learning HTML.

Is this a good way to start learning programming? Will it help me in the future with learning important programming languages like C++?

Comment: Good start for web pages? Yes (but get a fairly recent book, and also look at CSS).  Will it help to prepare for c++? No. Next step: Javascript (which might prepare you for c++ just a little).

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read the [faqs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting questions here.

Comment: @user162761112 Firstly HTML is not a programming language it is a markup language.Html will be useful if in future you plan to get into Web Development.Html is not neccessarily required to learn programming.

Comment: HTML is a markup language, not a programming language.

Comment: Learn HTML & XML, then javascript & DOM - install the firebug plugin for Firefox

Comment: I think we can just comment and make it clear to the OP rather than just downvotes.Let him know what is wrong with the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and No.

If you want to make web pages, then HTML is pretty much essential.

But it's not a programming language - it's a markup language for the transfer of information over the web. So it won't help you whatever language you choose next.

Answer (score 2):

HTML is no programming language. It is a markup language. But if you want to make webpages then of course you need to learn HTML.
After that it is a good idea to learn javascript (which is the programming language for the browsers) and a serverside language like PHP (or java/ruby/perl/python). This is needed for making good dynamic websites and a good starting point for learning other programming-languages like c++.

Comment: so, its more appropriate learning a programming language like c++ and when i have a good experience in this, enroll to a markup language like html? if so, what book/site do you propose for learning c++?

Comment: @user1627612 Why not learn both?Focus more on programming language and play around with Html,CSS whenever possible.

Comment: @freebird ok thats a fine solution thanks. Any good tutorial for c++. I had tried in the past learning it but some tutorials confused me

Comment: @user1627612 I think you can search this site for this.Have a look http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=tutorials+for+learning+c%2B%2B

Comment: @user1627612 a Markup Language is a method to structure a document - it has nothing to do with a programming language. You need to leran both. Since javascript is the dominant "programming language" for the web, it is best for you to learn HTML, since this is the Markup Language for the web, Javascript as clientside programming language and another programming language for serverside programming. Common Beginners Language is PHP for that.

Answer (score 0):

HTML is not a programming language, so no, it won't help you with languages like C++. However, just as knowing english is an important part of being an english writer, knowing HTML is something you'll need in order to be a web designer or developer.

Comment: Downvoter care to comment? I'm assuming you're the one that just gave every answer to this question a downvote.

Answer (score 0):

First, there isn't  any "important programming languages" : all depends of what you wanna do.
Actually, if you want to create web pages, some languages are very usefull as HTML, Javascript, PHP and others.

HTML won't help you to learn languages as C++, it's a totally different thing, but if you start programing, you should begin to learn C language (that is a programming language instead of HTML that is a markup language) or an easy script language as Python or Pearl (pretty interesting languages).

You should be able to find a lot of tutorials online.